# ui path rpa cant convert excel scraped data to post in pdf

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am able to fetch data from excel sheet but i am not able to print/publish/post data data in pdf or word i am basicaly try to fetch any excel data any specific no of rows or columns and want to post it in pdf

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to read a range and export said range to a PDF? Does each row have to go into a single PDF? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i  simply want that whenever i call any field row or columun i will get info related to that in a pdf format all that was provided in excel sheet i.e simply conversion of details related to particular type in a pdf file

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, UiPath can create PDF files when:

1. You are working with Word documents, in a `Word Application Scope` using the [Export to PDF activity](https://activities.uipath.com/v1.0/docs/word-export-to-pdf).
2. Via generic desktop automation. For example, if you have Microsoft Excel installed, you can open your file and then use [Save to PDF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-or-convert-to-pdf-or-xps-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110#ID0EAADAAA=Office_2010_and_Newer_Versions) via the menu.
3. Via a [custom activity](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/creating-a-custom-activity). While above methods have their restrictions, i.e. requiring you to work with either Word or Excel files, a custom activity can create a PDF from any other input, form, or format. My favorite library is [iText](https://itextpdf.com/), but you use just any other one to your liking to render the PDF.